# Definição Notação "Little-O" ( Pequeno O)

Tags: complexidade-de-algoritmo

Gostaria de entender um pouco melhor sobre a Notação Little-O, é para fins acadêmicos, porem não tenho encontrado conteúdo suficiente ou de uma forma um pouco mais "clara", para entendimento. Estou um pouco perdido em relação devido a falta de material para estudo.

Comment: Olá @Italo, bem vindo ao **StackOverflow PT**. Aproveite para fazer o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para perceber melhor o funcionamento do site.

Answer (score 1):

Nota: vou usar a letra `o` (miníuscula) para little-o; e `O` (maiúscula) para big-O

---

Dizemos que uma função `f` está contida em `o(g)` se para todo `x` é verdade que `f(x) < g(x)`.

Dizemos que uma função `f` está contida em `O(g)` se para todo `x` é verdade que `f(x) <= g(x)`.

Por exemplo, considere a função `f(x) = x^2`

- `f` está em `o(x^3)` e em `O(x^3)`
- `f` **não** está `o(x^2)` nem em `O(x)`

Note que se `f` estiver contida em `o(g)` então necessariamente estará em `O(g)` também.